# What does the thin line on my macOS dock designate?

Tags: macos, taskbar, dock

[image: Dock with several apps]

What does the line between FaceTime and my VPN app indicate? I notice that I can bring some apps from one side to the other but not vice versa.

I am running macOS 10.14.1. Thanks!

Comment: Aren't those the active tasks to the right?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist no, as you can see in the screenshot i have safari spotify and chrome open but they are on the left.

Answer (score 2):

On the right side of the separator you see what applications you recently opened.
This is a parameter that can be modified in the 'Dock' settings.

Comment: More specifically, non-pinned apps you opened. Pinned apps stay on the left, whether open or not.